# PHP code to filter data between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, date

I created a report in which I need to filter data between two dates.

```
Column name

bookingdate - varchar 

format --dd-mm-yyyy
```

Below is my code. This works but get all data, because I think my bookingdate filter not working properly.

Is there is any date conversion needed in my code?

```
if($_POST['fromdate']!='' && $_POST['todate']!='')
    {   
    $fromdate = $_POST['fromdate']; 
    $todate = $_POST['todate'];
    $cityname = $_SESSION['Auth']['city'];
    $data = $database->getRows("SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(coupon) as cou,GROUP_CONCAT(coupondate) as coupondt FROM receipt_entry WHERE city_name = :cityname AND bookingdate BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate GROUP BY book_no,receipt_no order by bookingdate asc"
    ,array(':fromdate'=>$fromdate,':todate'=>$todate,':cityname'=>$cityname)); 
    }
```

Comment: Which format fromdate and todate is coming ?

Comment: make sure all dates are in the same format ( YYY-MM-DD)

Comment: fromdate and to date is in same format   dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: Use a native `DATE` column to store dates. If you have them as strings, they're basically meaningless to MySQL. You can use `ALTER TABLE` to introduce a new column and `UPDATE` to convert them.

Comment: i need to ask you my query is correct or there is any conversion needed there...if i update my datatype from varchar to date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are messing up with the mysql standards.

- Fist thing you should store the dates in mysql native datatypes `date`,`datetime` or `timestamp`
- Any input date value you send to mysql should be converted to `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

So you first need to convert your input dates properly to the above format something as below assuming your input dates are also in `dd-mm-yyyy` format.

```
$fromdate = $_POST['fromdate']; 
$todate = $_POST['todate'];

$formdate_r = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $fromdate);
$todate_r = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $todate);

// This will have yyyy-mm-dd format
$formdate_sql = $formdate_r->format("Y-m-d"); 
$todate_sql = $todate_r->format("Y-m-d");
```

Using `DateTime::createFromFormat` you can convert any format from input.

Next in your query the date is varchar with format `dd-mm-yyyy` and its not a real date , so you need to convert to real date. The function `str_to_date` does it for you as

```
mysql> select str_to_date('08-01-2015','%d-%m-%Y') as date ;
+------------+
| date       |
+------------+
| 2015-01-08 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)
```

So the query will be as

```
$data = $database->getRows("SELECT *, 
                    GROUP_CONCAT(coupon) as cou,
                GROUP_CONCAT(coupondate) as coupondt 
                FROM receipt_entry 
                WHERE city_name = :cityname 
                AND str_to_date(bookingdate,'%d-%m-%Y') BETWEEN :fromdate AND :todate 
                GROUP BY book_no,receipt_no order by bookingdate asc
            ",array(':fromdate'=>$formdate_sql,':todate'=>$todate_sql,':cityname'=>$cityname));
```